# Google Cloud Storage Transfers Failing

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set up a scheduled transfer from one of the storage directories on my VPS to Google Cloud Storage.

I try to set up a daily job by doing the following:
-Go to google cloud console -> Storage - > Create Transfer Job
-I select Sources as "List of Object URLs"
-Destination as one of my coldline storage buckets
-Then I configure transfer to run daily

Problem is I tried running tests and it always fails.

This is how my tsv looks:

TsvHttpData-1.0
https:///directory/filename.ext 39679045    CXNN5NAoHHqjGJX1o0syxg==

I've checked the MD5 and the file URLs are all okay.
When I go to the transfer on the console and try to figure out what went wrong I get very generic error messages like "Unknown error"

[image of errors on cloud storage console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOE6V.png)

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. Can someone help me please?

This is my first post to this site, I am really sorry if this question does not belong here. Please help me out by pointing me to the right place to ask this question if that is the case.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue? If so it is recommended to post your solution as the answer here to better help the community. If not, make sure that the files you want to transfer are publicly accessible, and that your [tab separated file is properly formatted](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list).